DBeaver не подлючается к mysql
У меня есть удаленный сервер ubuntu, я скачал на него mysql, создал юзера:
Поставил ему хост, дал права к базе данных, но не могу подлючиться к dbeaver:

Что не так, подскажите
Выдает такое:


Откуда подключиться? Снаружи? Снаружи этот порт закрыт

DBeaver клиентское ПО, а судя по IP со скриншота - это удаленный сервер (+ автор это отметил) + по первому скриншоту - там asyncuser@localhost права доступа) в настройках юзера поставьте свой IP или % для всех возможных) параметр localhost позволяет подключатся к базе только из своего окружения (ПК, сервера, контейнера)..

CREATE USER 'asyncuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '123456pass'; / GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'asyncuser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
